# Setting the Transaction Isolation Level through Spring Boot properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, transactional

I have a spring boot application which I have configured most of the properties through the properties file. However, I was looking if there is a way to set the TRANSACTION_ISOLATION_LEVEL through the Spring boot properties. Could someone help me on this.

I'm initializing the data source bean in the following way:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return buildDataSource("spring.datasource");
}

private DataSource buildDataSource(String propPrefix) {
 Stirng driverClassName = env.getProperty(propPrefix + ".driver-class-name");
 return DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .driverClassName(driverClassName)
        .build();
}
```

Could someone please help me on how to specify the TRANSACTION_ISOLATION_LEVEL either through properties or during the data source initialization.

Comment: AFAIK, it depends on the concrete connection pool you're using. If using HikariCP, see https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP (and search for transactionIsolation).

Comment: I'm using the Spring JDBC connection pool.

Comment: Spring doesn't come with a connection pool. If you mean that you're using the default connection pool that Spring-Boot depends on, then check the doc of Spring-Boot to know what it is, then check its documentation.

Answer (score 3):

So, the **javax.sql.DataSource** does not provide a way to set default Transaction Isolation Level. **Still,** you can do it, but you must strict to particular implementation. Let me give you c couple of examples:

1. In case you use Apache BasicDataSource implementation of DataSource, then you can use [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#setDefaultTransactionIsolation%28int%29). **This is for DBCP.**
2. If you are using Apache BasicDataSource, **but for DBCP2**, you can do something like [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-2.0.1/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSource.html#setDefaultTransactionIsolation%28int%29).
3. But in most cases, if we are talking about Spring, we use Hikari Connection Pool. So, in case of HikariCP, you can use [this](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/master/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.java#:%7E:text=public%20void%20setTransactionIsolation(String%20isolationLevel)) method.

The same is applicable to Spring Boot. Let me explain - using Spring Boot properties file, you can set default transaction isolation level, but for specific DataSource, I mean this property:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.transaction-isolation
```

as you probably noticed, let you set default transaction isolation level for HikariCP (if you are using one) And this property:

```
spring.datasource.dbcp2.default-transaction-isolation
```

allow you to configure default isolation level for DBCP2.

Hope it helped, have a nice day! :)